# Override htaccess in subdir

Tags: apache, .htaccess, basic-authentication

Somewhat related to an earlier question of mine.  I have an .htaccess file at the top of my webapp that says this:

```
AuthType Basic
Require group producers
```

There's a 'clients' subdirectory and I want access to that subdir to require the admin group, and not allow the producers group.  I've not been able to figure out what to put in the .htaccess in the clients directory to make that happen.  Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting:

```
AuthType Basic
Require group admin
```

in the htaccess file in your `/clients/` directory doesn't work?